# iPads from different MDM server seeing update

Tags: ios, ipad, mdm

We have developed an in-house app which has been signed by our enterprise account. This app has been uploaded to three different MDM servers. We recently update the app and incremented the version number from 1.0 to 1.1 (we kept the build version number to 1.0.0).

MDM server [a] was updated with this new version (1.1) and then distributed to the devices under its control.

However, we have seen other iPads under the control of MDM servers [b] and [c] started showing a pop-up message when the app is launched. These mdm servers have yet to receive the new app update.

The message is "Updated available, Version 1.1 (1.0.0) is available".

Please can someone help me understand how this could have happened? Is it because they are all signed by the same enterprise account?

Does anyone know how this message can be supressed until those MDM servers [b] and [c] have been given the new version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so we have found that this was caused by the fact the app has some HockeyApp integration.